# Winapi: Could not register Signal handlers

Tags: windows, winapi, signals

Here is my code:

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 

BOOL CtrlHandler( DWORD fdwCtrlType ) 
{ 
  printf("I'm In...\n");
  fflush(stdout);

  switch( fdwCtrlType ) 
  { 
    // Handle the CTRL-C signal. 
    case CTRL_C_EVENT: 
     printf( "Ctrl-C event\n\n" );
     fflush(stdout);
     Beep( 750, 300 ); 
     return( TRUE );

   // CTRL-CLOSE: confirm that the user wants to exit. 
    case CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT: 
     Beep( 600, 200 ); 
     printf( "Ctrl-Close event\n\n" );
     fflush(stdout);
     return( TRUE ); 

    // Pass other signals to the next handler. 
   case CTRL_BREAK_EVENT: 
    Beep( 900, 200 ); 
    printf( "Ctrl-Break event\n\n" );
    fflush(stdout);
    return FALSE; 

   case CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT: 
    Beep( 1000, 200 ); 
    printf( "Ctrl-Logoff event\n\n" );
    fflush(stdout);
    return FALSE; 

   case CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT: 
    Beep( 750, 500 ); 
    printf( "Ctrl-Shutdown event\n\n" );
    fflush(stdout);
    return FALSE; 

   default: 
    return FALSE; 
 } 
} 

int main( void ) 
{ 
  if( SetConsoleCtrlHandler( (PHANDLER_ROUTINE) CtrlHandler, TRUE ) ) 
  { 
    printf( "\nThe Control Handler is installed.\n" ); 
    printf( "\n -- Now try pressing Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Break, or" ); 
    printf( "\n    try logging off or closing the console...\n" ); 
    printf( "\n(...waiting in a loop for events...)\n\n" ); 
    fflush(stdout);

    while( 1 ){ } 

  } 
  else 
  {
    printf( "\nERROR: Could not set control handler");
    fflush(stdout); 
    return 1;
  }

return 0;
}
```

As you Can see I'm using example provided in msdn website, but my problem is that, when I launch application 
 `The Control Handler is installed.`

`-- Now try pressing Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Break, or`
   `try logging off or closing the console...`

`(...waiting in a loop for events...)`
 gets printed but when I hit CTR+C nothing happens(nothing gets printed) and process terminates. I've added `fflush` function in several places to make sure thats it's not printing problem. Thanks.

Comment: Your handler is declared wrong, but your typecast is hiding that error from the compiler. Get rid of the typecast and the compiler will complain as expected. You need to change the handler declaration to `BOOL WINAPI CtrlHandler( DWORD fdwCtrlType )`. Without the `WINAPI` your handler is using the wrong calling convention.

Comment: In other words, you lied to the compiler. Don't do that!